# Converting a CFStringRef to char *

Tags: c, macos

I am getting a `CFStringRef` out of a `CFDictionaryRef` using `CFDictionaryGetValue`.

I've been trying to convert the `CFStringRef` to a `char*` using `CFStringGetCString` or `CFStringGetCStringPtr` and they either return a NULL or it crashes.

Is there a way to do this? How?

Thank you.

EDIT: sample code:

```
SecStaticCodeRef staticCode;
CFDictionaryRef information;
SecCSFlags flags = kSecCSInternalInformation
            | kSecCSSigningInformation
            | kSecCSRequirementInformation
            | kSecCSInternalInformation;    
CFURLRef pathURL = NULL;
CFStringRef pathStr = NULL;
CFStringRef uniqueid;
char* str = NULL;
CFIndex length;


pathStr = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault,  
                                    filename, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);    
pathURL = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, pathStr, NULL);
SecStaticCodeCreateWithPath(pathURL, kSecCSDefaultFlags, &staticCode);
SecCodeCopySigningInformation(staticCode, flags, &information);      

uniqueid = (CFStringRef) CFDictionaryGetValue(information, kSecCodeInfoUnique);

// how do I convert it here to char *?
length = CFStringGetLength(uniqueid);
str = (char *)malloc( length + 1 );
CFStringGetCString(uniqueid, str, length, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

printf("hash of signature is %s\n", str);

CFRelease(information);
CFRelease(staticCode);
```

Comment: How does your crashing code for `CFStringGetCString()` look? Have you checked the [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/Articles/AccessingContents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001184-100980-TPXREF112)?

Comment: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFData _getCString:maxLength:encoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100503460'` followed by a dump of the stack

Comment: I mean your code where you are using this.

Comment: Check the question, I added the code

Comment: Meaning? I can run this on objective-C and it return the string I am looking for. I am initializing it anyway.

Comment: If `uniqueid` is a CFDataRef (not CFStringRef), then you can use [`CFStringCreateWithBytes()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001211-CH201-F11121) and pass the result of [`CFDataGetBytePtr`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFDataRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFDataGetBytePtr).

Comment: Could you post a little snippet. I am confused now. Thanks

Comment: It is worth mentioning that if you are using __Objective-C__, you can use a `__bridge NSString*` cast, `NSString* ns = (__bridge NSString*)cfStr ;  char* regStr=[ns UTF8String] );`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the Chapter 17 [example code](http://robnapier.net/bookcode) in [iOS:PTL](http://robnapier.net/book).

```
char * MYCFStringCopyUTF8String(CFStringRef aString) {
  if (aString == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }

  CFIndex length = CFStringGetLength(aString);
  CFIndex maxSize =
  CFStringGetMaximumSizeForEncoding(length, kCFStringEncodingUTF8) + 1;
  char *buffer = (char *)malloc(maxSize);
  if (CFStringGetCString(aString, buffer, maxSize,
                         kCFStringEncodingUTF8)) {
    return buffer;
  }
  free(buffer); // If we failed
  return NULL;
}
```

The resulting buffer must always be freed (which is why `Copy` is in the name). The linked example code also has a slightly faster version that uses a buffer you provide.

Comment: Since the question changed, and so did the answer, which problem are you now trying to fix?

Comment: the question did not change. How do I get that value onto a char * ?

Comment: An `NSDataRef` is not a string. It's not a sequence of human readable characters. Do you want to translate it into something else that is human readable (but not the original value)? `CFCopyDescription()` will give you that.

Comment: so maybe I am doing wrong. I have `CFStringRef s; s = CFDictionaryGetValue(information ,kSecCodeInfoUnique); NSLog(@"S =  %@", s);` and that in objective-c gives me the hash number I am looking. how do I do this in C?

Comment: I bet what's you're seeing in ObjC is something like @"<dead beaf ....>". Correct? Particularly that it has angle brackets around it. That's the output of `description`. The exact same output is available from `CFCopyDescription()`. But it's not a string. It's an `NSData`. In ObjC you're just getting away with it because you never call something that checks if it's really a string.

Comment: Cool. Now I know. How do i solve this. Or, how do I print a hex representation of this?

Comment: CFCopyDescription() will give you a hex representation string, just like in ObjC.

Comment: which bring me to the original question. CFCopyDescription returns a CFStringRef, how do I get that into a char *?

Comment: Rolled-back the answer. That will convert a CFStringRef to a char*. You didn't have a CFStringRef before. If you use CFCopyDescription(), you will.

Comment: One correction needed. If CFStringGetCString() fails then buffer should be released.

Comment: I strongly suspect that this answer has a serious flaw to it - the `CFStringGetMaximumSizeForEncoding()` function doesn't seem to include the null terminator, so you have to do `maxSize + 1` when `malloc`ing (EDIT:) AND when calling `CFStringGetCString()`. Just got burned by it with some Chinese strings. You're welcome to vote this comment up - let's reduce software crash rates around the globe.

Comment: Should the buffer be released if CFStringGetCString() fails as Omkar said in his comment? If so, please update your answer ! @RobNapier

Answer (score 17):

Another answer:

```
const char *cs = CFStringGetCStringPtr( cfString, kCFStringEncodingMacRoman ) ;
puts( cs ) ; // works
```

I can't find the reason why `kCFStringEncodingUTF8` gives NULL, but  `kCFStringEncodingMacRoman` seems to work fine.

Comment: Actually this returns nil for me. <sulk>

Comment: I know that this is VERY old, but, read here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542133-cfstringgetcstringptr `A pointer to a C string or NULL if the internal storage of theString does not allow this to be returned efficiently.`

Comment: Apparently, `NULL` is also returned if the string is just 0 or 1 characters. :|

Answer (score 11):

There is an another one line solution for the same problem:

```
char * myCString =  [(__bridge NSString *)myCfstring UTF8String];
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 6):

why not simply: `printf("%s\n", CFStringGetCStringPtr(uniqueid, kCFStringEncodingUTF8));`?

Answer (score 4):

very simple:

```
CFStringEncoding encodingMethod = CFStringGetSystemEncoding();
const char *path = CFStringGetCStringPtr(cfStrRef, encodingMethod);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [String Programming Guide for Core Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/Articles/AccessingContents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001184-CJBEHAAG)  Documentation. Here is how you get the Contents of a CFStringRef as a C String.

I have made a modification to it as so, this should do what you are looking for.

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>


CFStringRef str;
//Removed CFRange
const char *bytes; //This is where the conversion result will end up.



str = CFSTR("You Want this String!\n"); //Changed this part

bytes = CFStringGetCStringPtr(str, kCFStringEncodingMacRoman);



if (bytes == NULL) 
{
    //Adding in getting the size
    CFIndex stringLengthIndex = CFStringGetLength(str);

    //Converted index (signed long ) to int
    char localBuffer[(int) stringLengthIndex];

    Boolean success;

    success = CFStringGetCString(str, localBuffer, stringLengthIndex, kCFStringEncodingMacRoman);

}
//At this point the "bytes" variable should contain your C string copied from the provided CFStringRef
```

Comment: These Apple docs are hopelessly misleading. There are numerous errors in the above code (and the Apple code strongly encouraged you to make those errors). Your buffer goes out of scope too soon and throws away your result. `bytes` doesn't point to the string if `CFStringGetCStringPtr` failed. The "10" in `CFStringGetCString` is wrong (it should be stringLengthIndex at a minimum). `CFStringGetLength` may be too short for some encodings. Etc. It's not your fault; the Apple code is, as I say, hopelessly misleading. Look in my answer and in the sample code it links for correct ways to do this.